# Nested foreignkey query

Tags: django, foreign-keys, nested

Using a model like this:

```
class Folder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField()

class CanAccess(models.Model):
    folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Image(models.Model):
    folders = models.ManyToManyField('Folder')
    title = models.CharField()
```

I need to find all the images that a user can access.

I have tried this, but its not working:

```
images=Image.objects.filter(folders__canaccess_set__user=current_user)
```

I get an `FieldError` when Django looks up the `canaccess_set` part.

Whats is the best way to make such a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the info found here:

http://bitkickers.blogspot.dk/2010/04/django-manytomany-error-cannot-resolve.html

indicated that load order of the model could yield this kind og error, so i changed the models.py file from this order:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    folders = models.ManyToManyField('Folder')
    title = models.CharField()

class Folder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField()

class CanAccess(models.Model):
    folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

to this order:

```
class CanAccess(models.Model):
    folder = models.ForeignKey("Folder")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Image(models.Model):
    folders = models.ManyToManyField('Folder')
    title = models.CharField()

class Folder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField()
```

And that actually seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `_set` when doing a lookup:

```
Image.objects.filter(folders__canaccess__user=current_user)
```

Comment: I have tried without _set, but receives an error: Cannot resolve keyword 'canaccess' into field. Choices are [list of declared model fields]